# the apm(the package manager of atom) start shell run error

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, electron, atom-editor

I am dealing with a bug of apm in my osx 10.11 system. When I run

```
apm
```

in my command line, it throw an error because of the wrong file path:

```
/usr/local/bin/apm: line 32: /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/.bin/node: No such file or directory
```

After checked out, I found that:
In the apm shell(/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/.bin/apm), there is a while loop:

```
while [ -L "$binDir" ]
do
  binDir=`readlink "$binDir"`
  builtin cd "`dirname "$binDir"`"
  binDir=`basename "$binDir"`
done
```

It seems like this loop runs only one time on my osx system and runs twice on others, the bug which I have is because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-L` checks whether the file is a symbolic link and returns True if so. From `man test`:

```
   -L FILE
          FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -h)
```

See an example where we create a file `hello` and a (soft)link to it called `my_link`:

```
$ touch hello
$ ln -s hello my_link
$ [ -L "hello" ] && echo "this is a link" || echo "this is NOT a link"
this is NOT a link
$ [ -L "my_link" ] && echo "this is a link" || echo "this is NOT a link"
this is a link
```

Comment: yes, I understand what the  "-L" means in shell, but could you see my code? I don't understand why this loop runs just one time in my osx. It runs twice on another mac osx. The system is same.

Comment: @zhuyingda `while` keeps looping to find the original file that is linked. It is unclear what exactly is happening, but try to `echo` `$binDir` to see where it gets stuck. It looks like `/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/.bin/node` is broken, so you may have a nodejs configuration issue.

Comment: When the first loop of this
    while
loop runs over, the value of $binDir is still "apm", I don't know why the loop do not runs second time? third time?

Comment: @zhuyingda what if you run this manually? `readlink "apm"` in the directory  where it exists. Also, do `ls -l apm` and see the first character. Is it `l`? (=L, for link)

Comment: yeah, as you say, the readlink "apm" in the directory , where there is a symbol link "apm" exists , would not match the apm in $PATH(/usr/local/bin/apm) but the apm in current dir.  I understand , thanks a lot.